# How to use vector in F# 4.1

Tags: f#

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

let c = vector [ 5.0; 8.0 ];
```

And I got many errors :

- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error   FS0076  #r directives may only occur in F# script files (extensions .fsx or .fsscript). Either move this code to a script file or replace this reference with the '-r' compiler option. If this directive is being executed as user input, you may delimit it with '#if INTERACTIVE'/'#endif'.  Practive    c:\users\ai for robotics\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Practive\Practive\Program.fs 1   Active
- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error   FS0039  The value or constructor 'vector' is not defined.   Practive    c:\users\ai for robotics\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Practive\Practive\Program.fs 9   Active

Comment: The Fsharp Powerpack has been depreciated. You should probably use[MathNet.Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) instead. Drop by Slack or F# chat if you need more help.

Comment: From your answer, it looks like you do not really need vectors to do what you want to do - what is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I fond my answer that it's simple for beginners as me . 
 - It's use ***ResizeArray***
 - And this's a example for my problems :

```
 let vector = ResizeArray<float>()
 vector.Add(1.0)
 vector.Add(2.0)
 printfn "CONTENTS"
 vector |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%f" x)
 // add range
 vector.AddRange([3.0;4.0;5.0])
 printfn "CONTENTS"
 vector |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%f" x)
 // remove
 vector.RemoveAt(2)
 printfn "CONTENTS"
 vector |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%f" x)
 // insert
 vector.Insert(0,42.)
 printfn "CONTENTS"
 vector |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%f" x)
```

Comment: This is basically writing C# with F# syntax: you're "mutating" (changing in-place) the value you've assigned to the name `vector`. F# tries to encourage you **not** to do that: values once assigned should be immutable, which is why F# functions that add to a list will *return a new list* rather than changing your existing list. You seem to be a beginning programmer, so the reason why immutability is so important will not be immediately obvious to you. But I would encourage you to go to http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/why-use-fsharp-intro/ and read through that series as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

the #r command is for .fsx files, you are in a .fs file. If you were to create a new file with the fsx extension, the above would work. However you would need a path to the FSharp.PowerPack.dll the below code works on my machine

```
#r """C:\Users\josep\exercism\fsharp\hello-world\packages\FSPowerPack.Core.Community.2.0.0.0\lib\Net40\FSharp.PowerPack.dll"""

let c = vector [ 5.0; 8.0 ];
```

But since you are using .fs, I think an easier way to fix the issue you are facing would be to remove the #r line, and just go to nuget and Install-Package FsPowerPack.Community

Then your code should just work.

Comment: But I using Fsharp in Webite which only follow using Fsharp 4.1

Comment: Search your c drive for FSharp.PowerPack.dll, then add a reference to that in your project. If it doesn't exit, go to nuget and grab the Community version.